# wkhtmltopdf print-media-type uses @media print ONLY and ignores the rest

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I have an HTML file that uses one CSS file. Inside this file at the very bottom, I use this for styles that need to be applied ONLY to the printer version of the page:

```
@media print{
   ....print styles here...
}
```

When I call `wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type input.html output.pdf`, it renders the pdf with styles that are only in the `@media print` enclosure and ignores the rest of the styles - which DO NOT have `@media` type specified.

Is this normal, or what am I doing wrong here? Do I need to specify all styles for print inside `@media print`?

Answer (score 19):

wkhtmltopdf has an argument `--print-media-type` you can pass. Here is a C# code example using NReco (for illustrative purposes only), but the parameter should work in exactly the same way:

```
        var converter = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
        converter.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--print-media-type";
        var pdfBytes = converter.GeneratePdf(html);
        return pdfBytes;
```

This works fine for me in C# using NReco to use print media css, and it takes into account any CSS that is not inside a `@media` block too, such as the `font-size` of a `h3`. Try changing the size of the text or something similar and see if the change is reflected.

Comment: You are using `NReco.PdfGenerator`; he is using [`wkhtmltopdf`](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (and probably not C#), so, you are not answering his question in any meaningful way :(

Comment: The converter.CustomWkHtmlArgs are the same. My answer is simply telling him the arguments to use for WkHtml, I will make this more clear in the answer.

Comment: For Rotativa (which uses wkhtmltopdf), this is how to do it: `return new ViewAsPdf("Receipt", receiptModel)
    {
     FileName = "Receipt.pdf",
     CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type"
    };`

Answer (score 19):

By default, any CSS rules you define without using media queries applies to all media types.

Therefore, `wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type` will explicitly use `@media print` **AND** any other generic rules.

If you want rules that `wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type` will not use, you must specifically define the media query as anything other than `print`, for example:

```
@media screen {
  /* will not be used */
  ...
}

@media print {
  /* will be used */
  ...
}

/* any rules outside specific media queries will also be used */
div.foo {
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, including the CSS file in your HTML with `media="screen"` attribute will not be used with `wkhtmltopdf --print-media-type`:

```
<!-- will not be used -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='foo.css' type='text/css' media='screen'>
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks